# Varying class calling common method

Tags: java, class, selenium, methods

Warm wishes to all contrbutors,

I have an trivial yet niggling issue in trying to allow various class calling a common class to invoke a common method.

I have a class called `CommonLogin` which performs a login action, I also have a class, `TestA` which will call the `CommonLogin` class, run the login action, and then return to `TestA` to continue execution.  The returning to `TestA` is done by the method `TestA.runTest(testcase,url)` which is the `CommonLogin` class.

However, class `TestA` is just one of the many classes that is calling `CommonLogin` class to run the same login function. My issue is that I wish to make the class name in `TestA.runTest(testcase,url)` as a variable, but maintaining the method `runTest`. The desired outcome is as follows:

`classname.runTest(testcase, url);`  ==> initial syntax in code in `CommonFunction` class

If class `TestA`is executed,  then the above syntax will be designated as
`TestA.runTest(testcase, url);`

During the second round of execution, a class called `TestB` is executed, and this will designate the above syntax with 
`TestB.runTest(testcase, url);`

The reason to have the syntax `classname.runTest(testcase, url)` is to allow different class calling to the `CommonLogin` class to run the `runTest` method.

At the moment, in my `CommonLogin` class, I am using an if-else if statement, whereby if `TestA` class is calling, run the common Login action and then the `TestA.runTest(testcase, url)`. If `TestB` class is calling, then run the common Login action and then `TestB.runTest(testcase, url);`. In this way, my code consists of two chucnks of Login action, just that it is invoking the different method. If TestC, D, E and so on comes in, I will have a huge chunk of replicas of Login action, in which I am trying to avoid.

Thank you in advance for the advice.

Comment: It's very hard to follow the question. Could you provide some sample code, and show what you've already tried please?

Comment: Hi @Mureinik, thank you for your advice. Here is the link to the codes for your reference https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B5ummyLW4FRrZkN6VXhUM1Nub1U

Answer (score 0):

Using a class as a variable could be done with `.class` and reflection; your login method could use reflection to search your class for a `runTest` method and execute that.  However, that's more complicated than you need.

Assuming you're using Java 8 (I hope so, since Java 7 is past end-of-life), I think the best way is to provide, as a parameter, a method reference for a method to run the test.  The test method presumably takes two arguments and does not return a result.  Java already defines a number of built-in interfaces for purposes like this.  See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/package-summary.html.  The one you probably want is `BiConsumer`, which takes two arguments and does not produce a result.  So your login method could look like:

```
public ..whatever.. login(...other parameters..., BiConsumer<TestCase, String> testMethod) { ... }
```

I don't know what class the "testcase" you're referring to is; replace `TestCase` with whatever is appropriate.  Now, inside your login method, you'd call the test like this (assuming `testCase` is a `TestCase`):

```
testMethod.accept(testCase, url);
```

`accept` is the name of the interface method in `BiConsumer`.  (Other classes in that package use different method names, e.g. `apply`.)

When you call the login method, assuming your class declares a `runTest` method:

```
public void runTest(TestCase testCase, String url) { ... }
```

you'd call the login method like this:

```
CommonLogin.login(....., this::runTest);
```

which passes a reference to `runTest` that will run on the "this" object.  If `runTest` is static, however, you could call it like this:

```
CommonLogin.login(....., TestA::runTest);
```

Either way, you'll be passing a reference to a method, and `login` will call that method when it calls `testMethod.accept`.

(Note that when you do this, the method doesn't have to be named `runTest`.)

Comment: Thank you so much @ajb for your effort in providing such a comprehensive explanation. As I am not very familiar with `BiConsumer`, let me go through the basics of it first. But thanks again for your time and effort.